# When should I update 'due date' in JIRA?

Tags: agile, project-management, software, jira

Me and my collegue were having a discussion about when assignee should update 'due date' of the task in JIRA. My point is, assinee should update 'due date' only after he starts working over it so that he has some idea about the time estimate of efforts required. His idea is that 'due date' should be set by managers so that they could provide and manage timeline of the product. There are no right and wrong answers of this question, I just want to know what community thinks about it.

Comment: 'Due date' should be updated to 'tomorrow' after resolving the issue, so you never have issues overdue. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Updating the due date to reflect a time estimate frankly makes no sense. The issue is *already due* before work started on it, whether that's tomorrow or in six months. Due dates are parameters *to* the development team, not feedback *from* it.

The *estimate* field is what should be used to provide the estimate, either in story points, hours, etc.

The *product owner* or your *manager* should set the due date (if the field is used at all) based on input from stakeholders, according to the release schedule for the feature/bug fix involved, or whatever other criteria are used by the company.

If it's known that there isn't enough time to complete an issue before the PO or management requires it to be done, then that discussion has to be had before work begins. Something will have to be dropped, more resources added, or, the due date will have to be changed.